# Convert observable to jsx component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have an observable which will give json object at any time. For simplicity let's take below as example

```
// observable that emits a number after every 1 second
const $dynamic = from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(concatMap(x=>of(x).pipe(delay(1000) )))
```

*I just took an example here, in real $dynamic could get new value any time.*

Now what I want is to have a list of jsx component and I want them to update as soon as new entry is pushed in `$dynamic`

```
function MyApp() {
    return <>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>      <!------- Those entries should be loaded dynamically from $dynamic because  new entries could errive in $dynamic -->
    </>
}
```

So how I can subscribe to `$dynamic` in such a way that I can have list of elements as shown above and if new entry comes, it should be reflected there.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the observable in `useEffect` hook then set new value to local state in `next` callback. Each time the local state of a component is changed, the rendering of the component is triggered.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { from, of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const $dynamic = from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
    concatMap((x) => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    $dynamic.subscribe((x) => setItems((pre) => pre.concat([x])));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((v, idx) => {
        return <p key={idx}>{v}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-grothendieck-nwjn5?file=/src/App.tsx)